# pass a multi-value as parameters in pyramid URL Dispatch (add_route)

Tags: python, routes, pyramid

how to configure and use multidict in pyramid.

```
config.add_route('show_choosed_categories', '/categories/[list]')
```

and generate the urls like

```
${request.route_url('show_choosed_categories', categories=[1, 2] )}
```

in view i would use

```
request.GET.getall('categories')
```

pyramid seems to support it by webob.multidict – multi-value dictionary object https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/api/multidict.html

but how to use it with URL Dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

The route you have configured would match only on a string literal `[list]`.  Routes cannot match on Python objects, only strings and replacement markers.  From [Route Pattern Syntax under URL Dispatch](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#route-pattern-syntax):

> A pattern segment (an individual item between `/` characters in the pattern) may either be a literal string (e.g., `foo`) or it may be a replacement marker (e.g., `{foo}`), or a certain combination of both.

Nonetheless you can extract a multidict from the request object.

```
# Conjugation of English verbs is horrible
config.add_route('show_chosen_categories', '/categories/')
```

Assuming you have a list of checkboxes named the same or a select multiple input in a form, with either input being named `category`, then your request parameters would be generated to look like this:

```
category=1&category=2
```

Then any URL that begins with `categories` would be matched, and request parameters would be usable in your view, depending on your form action:

```
# form action="POST"
request.POST.getall('category')
# form action="GET"
request.GET.getall('category')
>>> [1, 2]
```

See [Multidict under Request and Response Objects](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html#multidict) for further information.

Comment: this way would work, expected more from routes in pyramid.
I would like to generate url like /categories/1/2/3/4/5 or /categories/1/2 
Sure i can also use for example json as value of categories or parse out the list separated by , . That's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Pyramid follows [RFC 2396](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#section-3.3) for path segments, where `/` is a reserved character that defines the boundaries of URL path segments. Another option would be to construct URLs like `/categories/1|2|3` then split on the pipe character.

Comment: Yes,  but pyramid uses multidict to work with parameters but not support it in the route implementation? That's a little bit confusing.
I don't need to do exactly /categories/1/2/3/4/5
sure it's possible to call /categories/1|2|3 or /categories/{JSON}

or normal categories=1&categories=2&categories=3.

The questions is how I can do it with route or it simply not implemented and i have to cook own solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `config.add_route('foo', '/categories/*subpath')` and `request.route_url('foo', subpath=(1, 2, 3)`. Support for this is limited but it does work if it fits your use cases. Note that an empty list is valid here so you need to handle that.

Comment: TIL. Link to Glossary term in docs: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/glossary.html#term-subpath